# FCM Plugin missing dependency

Tags: cordova, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Ionic 2. In order to make use of Googles Push Notification Service, I need to install [this](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm):

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm`

However, after doing so, I get this error when I try build the app:

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
   Searched Location:
  E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo\platforms\android\src\debug\google-services.json
  E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo\platforms\android\google-services.json

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

So it appears to be missing the dependency `google-services.json` I think. Do I need to install it? How?

If anyone can assist I would appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution

I copied `google-services.json` to `\platforms\android`.